# What's the equivalent of Vyper's create_forwarder_to in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, vyper

In Vyper, there's a built-in function called [`create_forwarder_to`](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/built-in-functions.html?highlight=create_forwarder_to#create-forwarder-to), which

> Duplicates a contract’s code and deploys it as a new instance, by means of a DELEGATECALL.

If my understanding is correct, what `create_forwarder_to` does is:

- Choose an existing contract instance `A`.
- Deploy a new contract `B` that will behave the same as `A` by delegatecalling `A`'s functions whenever there's an incoming function call to `B`.

The size of bytecode of `B` can be extremely small, since it's not deploying `A` again but deploying a *forwarder* contract that utilizes `A`'s bytecode.

Here is an example of [a forwarder contract in Uniswap](https://etherscan.io/address/0x09cabec1ead1c0ba254b09efb3ee13841712be14#contracts), and you can see how the forwarder contract is deployed in [the factory contract of Uniswap](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95#contracts). (`create_forwarder_to` was called `create_with_code_of` before and got renamed in [this release](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html?highlight=create_with_code_of#v0-1-0-beta-9).)

How can I do what `create_forwarder_to` does with Solidity?

Comment: You have to use a proxy contract https://swende.se/blog/EVM-Assembly-trick.html

Answer (score 1):

In solidity it doesnt have that builtin function but you can create it with eip1167(i think in vyper they implement this as builtin function instead of let you code it your self which is safer): https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167. It is implemented in this github you can check out: https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory?files=1

Comment: One of the original clone-factory devs here. Just want to add that the optionality/clone-factory library is outdated/deprecated. I suggest using Openzeppelin's implementation of EIP-1167 at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol